# Putting a total ordering into set theory compatible with the Ackermann interpretation on $V_\omega$.

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, model-theory

Let's extend the language of ZF with a new relation-symbol $\le$ and add axioms asserting that it is a total ordering:

$\forall_x (x \le x)$

$\forall_x \forall_y (x \le y \vee y \leq x)$

$\forall_x \forall_y ((x \le y \land y \le x) \rightarrow x = y)$

$\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z((x \le y \land y \le z) \rightarrow x \le z)$

Suppose there is a strongly inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, so $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZF.  Then I believe there is also a model of the extended theory, since we can totally order $V_\kappa$ in some arbitrary way and use that as our interpretation of $\leq$.  A technicality is that Separation now has additional instances asserting the existence of new sets like $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : x \leq y \}$.  But all these sets were already in $V_\kappa$ so $V_\kappa$ is also a model of the extended theory which is therefore a conservative extension of ZF.  Stop me there if any of the above is wrong.

The general question motivating what follows is what can we say to relate $\leq$ and $\in$ and keep the theory consistent?

For example I claim we can add the following axioms as well:

$A \equiv \forall_x \forall_y ( x \leq y \leftrightarrow (x \setminus y) \leq (y \setminus x))$

$B \equiv \forall_x \forall_y ((\exists_z(z \in y \land \forall_w(w \in x \rightarrow w \lt z))) \rightarrow x \lt y)$

$C \equiv \forall_x \forall_y (\text{rank}(x) \subset \text{rank}(y) \rightarrow x \lt y)$

So one sufficient condition for $x \lt y$ is $x \subset y$ (implied by $A$), another is that $y$ contains an element larger than every element in $x$ ($B$), and another is that $x$ has a smaller rank than $y$ ($C$).  This suffices to define $\leq$ uniquely on $V_\omega$ (the hereditarily finite sets are ordered as Ackermann numbers) and by transfinite induction on rank we can give an interpretation of $\leq$ under which $A$ and $B$ and $C$ hold for all sets.  For each rank $V_{\alpha+1}\setminus V_\alpha$, we already know how to compare its elements with elements of earlier ranks by $C$ (they are always greater), so we just need to be able to compare them with each other.  Now $B$ defines a partial ordering on disjoint sets with the same rank, whose definition extends to the entire rank using $A$.
Finally choose a total ordering on $V_{\alpha+1}\setminus V_\alpha$ containing that partial ordering to define $\leq$ in the model: the set  $P((V_{\alpha+1} \setminus V_\alpha)^2)$ contains all relations on $V_{\alpha+1}\setminus V_\alpha$, so this can be accomplished using Specification and Choice.

Is that a valid argument that this theory is consistent if ZF is?

Comment: You keep talking about ZF without choice. Why can you well-order or linearly order anything without some choice? You can't, you just can't. And you keep using the words "choose" and "arbitrary", that should smack you on the forehead that you're going to need choice for this argument.

Comment: I'm assuming the meta-theory has Choice.

Comment: Maybe it is not clear that there are _two_ meanings of $\leq$ here.  One is as a relation-symbol in the theory with associated axioms.  Another is a total ordering defined on $V_\kappa$, a transitive model of that theory, existing in the meta-theory with Choice.  How can I explain this better?  I'm gaining some confidence that it's correct I guess I'm still not communicating it right.